# npm run start won't find node_modules folder on different OS aside Windows

Tags: node.js, linux, npm, nodemon, hapi.js

I made a node JS application using Hapi on Windows 10. After testing it locally, the script `start` would run without any problem. here is the start script inside the package.json

```
"scripts": {
"start": "nodemon  -e * ./src/server.js"
}
```

I am trying to deploy this app inside of Centos 7. After cloning from github, set up the postgreSQL DB & Table, set up the .env file, when I run the `npm run start` command, the console would pop up an error like so (error taken from Ubuntu instance on AWS, but the error are the same across every linux based OS)

```
[nodemon] starting `node node_modules nodemon.json package-lock.json package.json readme.MD src views /src/server.js`
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1032
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '/home/ubuntu/application_nodejs/node_modules'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1029:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:898:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

I tried to replicate the issue on Heroku, AWS EC2 running on Ubuntu & AMI 2, and my other Windows 10 PC. on Windows 10, the app would run with ease after running said command. On every linux based OS, it would return the same error. When I tried to run it with `node ./src/server.js`, the app would launch.

Is there any solution to my problem? I suspect it has something to do with file/folder naming or the start script itself. But I haven't found any correct solution. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to quote the `*`: `nodemon -e "*" src/server.js`.

Unlike Windows' cmd, Linux shells expand wildcards (as you can see in the command actually run, above the error). In Windows it's up to the program you are calling to expand wildcards. Since that is what you want in case of nodemon, it worked "by chance" on Windows without escaping the asterisk because it doesn't have any special meaning to cmd, but in Linux it will get expanded and that's not what you want.